# MassTransit RPC (RabbitMQ) timeout up with multiple clients

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have two node types. A `Server` and a `Client`. There will be 1 or more `Server` or `Client` currently running.

Using MassTransit and RabbitMQ, I am getting a timeout when trying the RPC pattern described [here](http://masstransit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview/request.html)).

The code for `Server` and `Client` is simple, for testing.

Code for `Server`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serviceBus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.UseRabbitMq();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://192.168.10.201/mybus_responder");

            sbc.Subscribe(x =>
            {
                x.Handler<TestEvent>((ctx, @event) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Received message " + @event.Message);
                    ctx.Respond(new TestEventResponse { Response = "Processed message \"" + @event.Message + "\"" });
                });

                x.Handler<TestEvent2>((ctx, @event) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Received message " + @event.Message);
                    ctx.Respond(new TestEventResponse2 { Response = "Processed message \"" + @event.Message + "\"" });
                });
            });
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Listening for events...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Code for `Client`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serviceBus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.UseRabbitMq();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://192.168.10.201/mybus");
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Ready to send events...");

        var eventType = false;

        while (true)
        {
            eventType = !eventType;

            var message = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName());

            Console.WriteLine("Sending message " + message);

            if (eventType)
            {
                serviceBus.PublishRequest(new TestEvent {Message = message}, configurator =>
                {
                    configurator.Handle<TestEventResponse>(response =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(response.Response);
                    });
                    configurator.SetTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                });
            }
            else
            {
                serviceBus.PublishRequest(new TestEvent2 {Message = message}, configurator =>
                {
                    configurator.Handle<TestEventResponse2>(response =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(response.Response);
                    });
                    configurator.SetTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I run exactly 1 of each node type, the commands/responses perform as expected. If I have more than 1 `Server` instances, the commmands/responses perform as expected, distributing `Client` requests evenly between each ```Server`` node.

However, if I have multiple `Client` instances running, I will get timeouts on the ```Client`` side.

Why is this? I require support for multiple ```Client`` instances, because this is my web-tier.

Comment: Change the client to use rabbitmq://192.168.10.201/*?temporary=true and you'll get a unique temporary queue for each client.

Answer (score 2):

Do, I believe this is simply because you end up sharing a queue between instances and they gobble each other's messages. Each client and sever needs a unique queue to read from.

Comment: I don't know how MassTransit makes you manage the queues. I just tried this in EasyNetQ, and it worked flawlessly. Setup was a lot easier. I decided to not user MassTransit. It is good for transport-agnostic implementations, but it is too opinionated for me.